# TypeError: Cannot read property 'fname' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is the HTML form. I  need to put the entries back to form when I click the Edit Button. It directs to the script function selectEdit()

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class=container>
        <form ng-submit="addItem()" name="myForm">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h1> Add Member </h1>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        <input type="text" placeholder="first name" ng-model="fname" required class="form-control"
        > <br> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="last name" ng-model="lname" required class="form-control"> <br> 
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" name="myEmail" class="form-control"> <br> 
        <span ng-show="myForm.myEmail.$error.email"> Not a Valid Email Address </span>
        <input type="number" placeholder="contact number" ng-model="contact" required class="form-control"> <br> 
        <input type="text" placeholder="address" ng-model="addres" required class="form-control"> <br> 
        <input type="submit" value ="Submit"> 
        </div>
        </div>

        </form>

        </div>

        <div class="container">

        <h1>  Address Book </h1>
        <hr>

            <table class= "table table-hover" > <br> <br>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Name </th>
                        <th>Email </th>
                        <th>Contact Number </th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Options</th>
                    </tr>   

                    <tr>
                        <th><input type="text" ng-model="searchFname" placeholder="search"> </th>
                        <th><input type="text" ng-model="searchEmail" placeholder="search"> </th>
                        <th><input type="text" ng-model="searchContact" placeholder="search"> </th>
                        <th><input type="text" ng-model="searchAddress" placeholder="search"> </th>
                        <th><input type="text" disabled="sfd" > </th>
                    </tr>       

                    <tr ng-repeat="x in address | orderBy: 'fname' | filter:{fname:searchFname, email:searchEmail, contact:searchContact, addres:searchAddress}"> 

                        <td> {{x.fname + " " + x.lname}} </td>
                        <td> {{x.email}} </td>
                        <td> {{x.contact}} </td>
                        <td> {{x.addres = $index}} </td>
                        <td> <input type="button" value="edit" ng-click="selectEdit($index)"> | <input type ="button" value="delete" ng-click="remove($index)"></td>

                    </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that I can't put back the entry to the form. It errors cannot read property 'fname' of undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

        app.controller("mainController", function($scope) {

            $scope.x = [];
            $scope.address= [];
            $scope.fname = "";
            $scope.lname = "";
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.contact = "";
            $scope.addres = "";

            $scope.addItem = function() {
                $scope.address.push({
                    fname: $scope.fname,
                    lname: $scope.lname,
                    email: $scope.email,
                    contact: $scope.contact,
                    addres: $scope.addres
                });

            $scope.fname = "";
            $scope.lname = "";
            $scope.email = "";
            $scope.contact = "";
            $scope.addres = "";

            };

            $scope.remove = function(index) {
                var isConfirmed = confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?");

                if(isConfirmed) {
                    $scope.address.splice(index,1);

                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }

            };

            $scope.selectEdit = function(index) {
                console.log(index);
                var chenes = getSelectedIndex(index);
                var list = $scope.address[chenes];
                $scope.fname = list.fname;
                $scope.lname = list.lname;
                $scope.email = list.email;
                $scope.contact = list.contact;
                $scope.addres = list.addres;


            };

            function getSelectedIndex(index){
            for(var i=0; i<$scope.address.length; i++)
                if($scope.address[i].index==index)
                    return i;
                return -1;  
        };

        });



    </script>
```

Comment: From which line does your error come from and is it from $scope or list?

Comment: In the script where the Edit Button is selected and directs to $scope.selectEdit = function(index)

Comment: Is list undefined after doing: var list = $scope.address[chenes];

Comment: Does list have an attribute called fname?

Comment: Add console.log(list) right after assigning it to see if its really what you want.

Comment: Yes that is. Im sorry, i'm just new to angularJS

Comment: it returns nothing but still undefined

Comment: I thought the list will linked to the index of what I want to get, is it?

Comment: The problem must be that getSelectedIndex does not return a valid value or $scope.address is empty/undefined.

Comment: Your getSelectedIndex function looks useless to me, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Great! Thank you! I just realized  that I subtracted the value that chenes gets. I am new to web dev but I got this job and needs to study more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the address array doesn't contain `chenes`,
Try to do console.log of chenes and address before this line: `var list = $scope.address[chenes];`

I have guessed that the property index doesn't exist in address items and the value of chenes is -1, and that's why `list` is undefined (what causes the error you have)